# installing ubuntu on win 10 :not working

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a new laptop Asus GL552v (ITerabyte, 128GB SSD and core i7600hq with WIN 10 home)
I would like to install ubuntu as what I do work mostly with Linux. I have read several blogs and comments on how to get this done but nothing seems to be working.
I have disabled fast startup, enabled CLI in Bios, I have tried to install using both liveCd and liveUsb but nothing works. Really, I often get to the page where i'm asked whether to try ubuntu or install, whenever i choose install, it brings out ubuntu window with some dots showing the progress, then it hangs at the last dot and stays lke that for several minutes to hours without showing any other option neither does it get past that. I have followed all the instructions and methods i could read online. is this problem peculiar to asus GL552V or is it because i only have win 10 home basic? or is there any other thing that i should do that I haven't done?
I would appreciate any help in getting this done. Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the asus homepage where your notebook is resented, because I couldn't find a model [Asus GL552v](https://www.asus.com/search/results.aspx?SearchKey=GL552v)? And please tell us which linux iso image you actually tried to install?

Comment: Some similar Asus: ASUS ROG GL552VW-CN104T
http://askubuntu.com/questions/694453/new-laptop-skylake-cannot-boot-xubuntu-even-with-boot-parameters Asus x555u w/o pci=nomsi - space issue on drive and runaway log files filling drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327103&page=3 and:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327570 But if RAID/Intel SRT: http://askubuntu.com/questions/861854/nvme-disk-configured-in-raid0-unable-to-install-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to an enabled secure boot setting in your BIOS.  Turn off this setting and try again.  This setting should be under the "boot" section of your BIOS.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu! While this answer explains the gist of things, can you please [edit] your answer to include a (little bit) more detailed instructions on how to do this? For example, where (generally) should I go into BIOS to find this setting?