# How to install ubuntu on on Asus ROG G701VIK

Tags: system-installation, asus, nvme

I have an ASUS ROG G701-VIK gaming laptop with 2* M2 SSD NVMe in a RAID-0 array in SATA mode and my BIOS has no option to change from SATA mode to AHCI mode.

When I'm trying to install Ubuntu, the installer does not detect my SSD.

Update:
- Now i'm installing ubuntu 18.04 on an external usb. 
- Cloned full ubuntu installation from usb to the second SSD.
- It's booting normally but to GNU GRUB screen .

```
grub> ls

hd0 (hd0,gpt1) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt4) hd1 (hd1,gpt1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt4)

grub> boot
You need to load kernel first.
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: i do not think you can change RAID 0, without totally erasing drives and reinstalling separately. Make sure you have good backups. If either drive fails you lose all data on both drives as half is on one & half on other alternating. See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/861854/nvme-disk-configured-in-raid0-unable-to-install-ubuntu-16-04  Many with NVMe drives have now installed Ubuntu, so that is not an issue.

Comment: i found some have have same my issues in same link u send it and he resolve this issues with raid 0 but he not share how ?
 Cereal Killer who did it

Comment: i don't know how to contact him ???? user:391046

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NVMe disk configured in RAID0 unable to install Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861854/nvme-disk-configured-in-raid0-unable-to-install-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: **Close voter warning:** Answer added: I have similar hardware. @EricCarvalho

Comment: OK, boot a liveUSB, go to a terminal, type `lshw`, [edit] your question and add the output there. Please use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Fabby : Done..

Comment: The SATA Controller is still in RAID mode in your BIOS.  You should turn that mode off.

Comment: ok i will break it now..and try same type lshw

Comment: When you break the RAID, you'll lose all info, so you do have a CloneZilla backup on an external disk do you?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76406/discussion-on-question-by-merocom-how-to-install-ubuntu-on-on-asus-rog-g701vik).

Comment: Related:https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en

Comment: @Elder Geek: same result didn't detected .... even i braked RAID 0 and now 2 separates SSD but still Intell RST shown it as a RAID 0:
Kernel message : Found 2 remapped NVMe devices, switch your BIOS from RAID to AHCI to use them.

Comment: Whats your BIOS version? Did you try [this answer?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026790/225694)

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.asus.com/US/support/FAQ/1029981?SearchKey=ahci/

Comment: Does ubuntu working fine if i cloned installation from external usb to SSD hard disk ??

Answer (score 0):

#### The best thing you can do is to remove the RAID-0 as RAID-0 is worse than no RAID at all.

It's a bit complex though and not for the faint at heart as no matter what, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd> will bring you into the Intel RAID Setup ROM so you have to:

- Take a [CloneZilla Live backup](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) of the pre-installed Windows 10 environment on the RAID-0 to another (bigger) disk
- Download [RTSCLI64 V 13.2.0_1016](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24310/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-Command-Line-Interface-CLI) and then [patch it](https://communities.intel.com/message/414989#414989) to ignore driver version checking.
- Boot Windows 10 into command prompt and delete the RAID array with the patched RSTCLI64:

  ```
    rstcli64 --manage --delete OEMRAID0
  ```
- Patch the CloneZilla image for it to be able to be [restored onto a smaller disk](https://serverfault.com/questions/568227/prepare-a-disk-to-be-imaged-by-clonezilla-for-use-on-smaller-disk)
- Restore the CloneZilla Image to one of the NVMes
- Install Ubuntu to the second NVMe

### Done!  :-)

<sup><sub>**Note:** I keep Windows around just to be able to change the keyboard background lights and to be able to do BIOS updates (haven't found a way around that yet)</sub></sup>

Comment: CloneZilla didn’t detected my SSD or RAID

Comment: I delete RAID 0 from bios and now it’s separate 2 NVME ssd also not detected by ubuntu installation

Comment: Any suggestions ??

Comment: Nothing happened, i'm feeling bored with my laptop

Comment: this link for laptop System76 : https://system76.com/laptops/bonobo. same my laptop specification specially M.2 PCI/SSD and hold Linux ????

Comment: Does it work for a G701 VIK?  I have the same issue.  I don't care about losing the windows partition, but I simply CANNOT break the RAID.  The BIOS gives no other options